# How can i use adjacent selector with :before?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-element, slick.js

Hi i'm writing timeline area has slick effect and i'm using slick.js for that. I have to changing my span's color. I changed first span in slick-active class element but my changes not working on other span elements. What can i do for that?

It's my code snippet:

https://jsfiddle.net/arg0dev/w7uzvhmn/20/

Please check /* ITS NOT WORKING */ comment area on .

HTML:

```
<section class="km-timeline" style="background: url('assets/materials/km-timelineBg.jpg');">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row min-vh-60 d-flex align-content-center">
            <div class="swipeKM text-center" id="timeline" > 
                    <div class="swiper-slide">
                      <div class="timestamp"><span class="date">2010</span></div>
                      <div class="status">
                        <span>Sub 1</span></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">
                      <div class="timestamp"><span class="date">2011</span></div>
                      <div class="status"><span>Sub 2</span></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">
                      <div class="timestamp"><span class="date">2013</span></div>
                      <div class="status"><span>Sub 3</span></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">
                      <div class="timestamp"><span class="date">2014</span></div>
                      <div class="status"><span>Sub 4.</span></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">
                      <div class="timestamp"><span class="date">2015</span></div>
                      <div class="status"><span>Sub 5</span></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">
                      <div class="timestamp"><span class="date">2017</span></div>
                      <div class="status"><span>Sub 6</span></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">
                      <div class="timestamp"><span class="date">2017</span></div>
                      <div class="status"><span>Sub 7</span></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">
                      <div class="timestamp"><span class="date">2019</span></div>
                      <div class="status"><span>Sub 8</span></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">
                      <div class="timestamp"><span class="date">2021</span></div>
                      <div class="status"><span>Sub 9</span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center mt-3">
                <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
                <button class="swiper-button-prev timelineNav me-3"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></button>
                <button class="swiper-button-next timelineNav"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
body .km-timeline .min-vh-60 {
  height: 500px;
  background: #dddddd
}

body .km-timeline .timeline {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

body .km-timeline .timestamp {
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 0px 4px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #011b83;
}

body .km-timeline .status {
  padding: 0px 10px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  border-top: dashed 2px #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
}

body .km-timeline .status span {
  padding-top: 35px;
  padding-bottom: 35px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #011b83;
}

body .km-timeline .status span:before {
  content: '';
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #b1b1b1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
}

body .km-timeline .active span {
  font-size: 19px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

body .km-timeline .active span::before {
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  background-color: #011b83 !important;
  border: 1px solid #011b83 !important;
}

body .km-timeline .swiper-container {
  width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body .km-timeline .swiper-wrapper {
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
  display: inline-flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
  overflow-y: auto;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}

body .km-timeline .swiper-container::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #a8a8a8b6;
}

body .km-timeline .swiper-container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 2px;
  display: none;
}

body .km-timeline .swiper-container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #4F4F4F !important;
}

body .km-timeline .swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

body .km-timeline .swiper-button-disabled {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) !important;
}

body .km-timeline .timelineNav {
  background: transparent;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

/* ITS WORKING */
.slick-active span:before{
  background-color: red;
}

/* ITS NOT WORKING */

.slick-active span:before + .slick-active span:before{
  background-color: #fff;
}

/* ITS NOT WORKING */
```

JS:

```
$('.swipeKM').slick({
  dots: false,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 5,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 320,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        infinite: true,
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 540,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 768,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3,
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
      slidesToShow: 5,
      }
    }
  ]

});
```

Thank's.

Answer (score 1):

Yuppy! It's worked finally! :)

Just i was added this code below:

```
.slick-current span:before{
  background-color: red !important;
}

.slick-active span:before {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Just i missed .slick-current element :)

Thank you so much.